# Debian 8 - kernel with vserver - apt can't find packages

Tags: debian, apt

```
apt-get install linux-image-2.6-vserver-686
apt-get nvidia-kernel-2.6-vserver-686
```

My apt can't find the above packages. What should I add to `sources.list`?
I have tried to find information in Google, but I didn't manage to.

My Debian is 8.0.
Piece of my source.list file:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main
```

Comment: I could swear VServers were taken out of the repositories for a while. No idea if they are back. Post your Debian version and the relevant line of your sources.list. I am getting out of home, but surely others will pick it up. You can also have a look at packages.debian.org

Comment: Post the requested details by editing your question, please.

Comment: It has been done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit [Linux Vserver installation on Debian](http://linux-vserver.org/Installation_on_Debia):

> Debian 6.0 'Squeeze' was the final version to include precompiled Linux-Vserver kernels [1](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=574529). In newer versions (including Debian Testing), you'll have to compile the kernel yourself or use a pre-packaged kernel. Information on alternative Debian repositories with more functional packages is [contained in this section of the FAQ](http://linux-vserver.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Were_can_I_get_newer_versions_of_VServer_as_ready_made_packages_for_Debian.3F). If you need to compile your own kernel, you need to apply the vserver-version.patch. See the [2](http://linux-vserver.org/Welcome_to_Linux-VServer.org)

You can not find Linux-Vserver Kernel images for Debian 8.0 (Jessie) as it is **removed** after Debain squeeze (7.0):

Visit: [Debian Bug report logs - #574529](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=574529):

> From: dann frazier 
>   To: Debian Bug Tracking System 
>   Subject: **release-notes: [SQUEEZE] vserver kernel flavors deprecated**
>   Date: Thu, 18 Mar 2010 14:24:33 -0600
>
> Package: release-notes
>   Severity: normal
>
> As mentioned in [1], the "vserver" featureset is planned to be removed
>   from the Debian linux kernel after the squeeze release. Debian suggests that
>   users consider migrating vserver systems to either the LXC (Linux Containers)
>   features of the upstream kernel or to the "openvz" featureset.
>
> [1] http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2009/10/msg00003.html

<sup>(emphasized by me)</sup>

Comment: Ok, when it comes to debian 6.0 - for this version can I install repository which I showed in my first post ?